# PHP get map position current street address does not appear

Tags: php

I am using a script to get lattitude and longitude, to show in a map right away after I load the page. The map appears, but it has shows position as empty, with just a comma (,) in the name instead of the current position. The name of the sreet does not appear. The marker appears in the middle of the world map.

It works with a position with fixed numbers, but it has to work with current position.

Code:

```
<div class="my-coloapse-body open"  id="my-coloapse-1" >
    <div class="map-section" >
        <div class="input-streename-row">
            <input id="streetname" type="text" name="name" class="" placeholder="όνομα δρόμου">
            <input name='longitude' id='longitude' type='hidden'/>
            <input name='latitude' id='latitude' type='hidden'/>

            <span class="relocate  ti-target " onclick="getMapLocation();"></span>
        </div>
        <div id="map"> </div>

        <?php $ITEMS = array(); //get_query("SELECT * FROM `pillars`"); ?> 

        <?php
        if (!filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'map-provider') == 'osm') {
            include("pillar-position-google.php");
        } else {
            include("pillar-position-osm.php");
        }
        $NOMALOCATION = 1;
        include(__DIR__ . "/../position-common.php");
        ?>
        <script>

            getMap('<?php echo $PILLAR["latitude"]; ?>', '<?php echo $PILLAR["longitude"]; ?>');

        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Function getmap:

// Get map by using coordinates

```
function getMap(latitude, longitude) {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
        zoom: 20,
        maxZoom: 20,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        styles: [{
                featureType: "poi",
                elementType: "labels",
                stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }]
            },
            { "featureType": "all", "elementType": "all", "stylers": [{ "saturation": -100 }, { "gamma": 0.5 }] }
        ],
        mapTypeControl: true,
        streetViewControl: false
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
    locations.forEach(function(location) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(location["lat"], location["lng"]),
            id: location["id"],
            icon: location["icon"],
            map: map
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(evt) {
            $.fancybox.open({
                src: '#dialogContent-' + this.id,
                type: 'inline',
                opts: {
                    afterShow: function(instance, current) {
                        console.info('done!');
                    }
                }
            });
            markers.push(marker);
        });
    });
    var latLong = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLong,
        draggable: true,
    });
    marker.setMap(map);
    map.setZoom(20);
    map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
        $("#streetname").val("...");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<?php echo APP_URL ?>get_address.php',
            data: {
                lat: marker.getPosition().lat,
                lng: marker.getPosition().lng,
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $("#streetname").val(data.trim());
            }
        });
        $("#latitude").val(marker.getPosition().lat);
        $("#longitude").val(marker.getPosition().lng);
    });
    $("#streetname").val("...");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<?php echo APP_URL ?>get_address.php',
        data: {
            lat: marker.getPosition().lat,
            lng: marker.getPosition().lng,
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $("#streetname").val(data.trim());
        }
    });
    $("#latitude").val(marker.getPosition().lat);
    $("#longitude").val(marker.getPosition().lng);
}
```

Edit:

The page seems to run 2 scripts as it takes. First it takes the default position on the map (0,0), and if I edit a fixed position, it refreshes after a few seconds in the current position (eg athens latitude and longitude)

```
function watchMapPosition() {

    return navigator.geolocation.watchPosition
    (onMapWatchSuccess, onMapError, { enableHighAccuracy: true });
}




// watchMapPosition();

getMapLocation();
</script>


    <script>
//  getMap( '37.94767073344734','23.734566048514125 ');
  </script>
```

[image: does not show name]

Comment: Have you checked where in your script that comma gets inserted? Is the markup generated by PHP in the proper format?

Comment: The comma appears because it does not find my current potition. It should be Town, (comma), street. See image

Comment: And which part of that code generates the comma? What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: Comma appears because it does not recognise the variables longitute and latitude.

Comment: Who is "it" that does not recognize these variables? Is the generated markup in the expected format? Whatelse have you tried to find the problem?

Comment: "It" is the page as it loads. 
It seems to run 2 scripts. First it takes the default position on the map (0,0), and if I edit a fixed position, it refreshes after a few seconds in the current position (eg athens latitude and longitude)

Updating the question.

Comment: So, can you finally answer my question: is the markup generated by PHP in the proper format?